# BPEL Persistence issue

Tags: web-services, glassfish, persistence, bpel, open-esb

It's very easy to turn persistence on in a Glassfish server, but what I've found is that this will persist all calls going through the system and some of these are synchronous calls that don't need to be persisted. This obviously affects server performance.

Is there a way to specify which bpel processes get persisted, for example BPELs representing synchronous calls wouldn't be persisted, whereas BPELs that represent asynchronous processes sitting in memory would be persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just found an option to do this. You can turn persistence on, then set a property on each bpel for 'per bp persistence opt out'.

Only problem with this is if you have an already existing set of synchronous services on glassfish, they all have to be changed to specify you want to opt out of persistence, otherwise they will all be persisted when you switch it on!